# How To Create a gRPC Service In C# For Google Assistant SDK?

Tags: c#, grpc, google-assistant-sdk

I want to communicate with the Google Assistant SDK via C#, and the SDK website said that for languages other than Python, I need to setup gRPC. Are there any good tutorials on this that I can use to get started? Thanks :)

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/

Comment: There is documentation available on the GRPC website: http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to use assistant API SDK from any language that support gRPC (including C#), but if there is not pre-build assistant SDK available (looks like there is one for python, not sure about other languages), it is a bit more involved to do that.
In short:
The .proto API definitions for all public Google APIs (including assistant API) live in "googleapis/googleapis" github repo:
https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/assistant/embedded/v1alpha1
In short, here's what you need to do:

1. grab .proto definitions for the API from github
2. generate proto messages/stubs in language of your choice (basically the same as in gRPC tutorials on grpc.io).
3. authenticate with google using an auth library 
   (http://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/auth.html)
4. invoke API calls using a client stub generated in step 2.

Btw, the Google API client libraries are basically a pre-packaged result of these steps, sometimes with a bit of convenience layer on top of it improve the user friendliness of a given API.

Also, usually support for more languages is added to new APIs over time (so at some point there might be and official C# client library).

Comment: Ok. I've downloaded the .proto definitions from the GitHub and I've used the ProtoCompiler to compile the embedded_assistant.proto into a .cs file. That's all correct for steps 1 and 2, right?

Comment: were u able to do it?? @NateDev

Comment: @Sana nope. Got errors in this file, tried a bunch of other stuff and errors there too, etc